# How to create comments using only * in COBOL?

Tags: cobol

I've just started reading about COBOL. In many articles they say that comment can be created using only `*`, I mean without using `*>`.

I tried to use it in column 1 and column 7 but I got syntax error in these online compilers: [1](https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-cobol-online/), [2](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cobol_online.php)

in column 1

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. HELLO-WORLD.
PROCEDURE DIVISION.
* Comment       
DISPLAY 'Hello, world'.
STOP RUN.
```

in column 7

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. HELLO-WORLD.
PROCEDURE DIVISION.
      * Comment       
DISPLAY 'Hello, world'.
STOP RUN.
```

ChatGPT also says that comment can be created using only `*`. Could anyone say what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Specifically, see [Brian Tiffin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17665688/2756409) on that question. Also, I have to caution against believing anything ChatGPT tells you (any version of it). It's not designed to understand or write code; it's designed to write believable prose.

Comment: @TylerH Do I understand it correctly - I got syntax error in online compilers because they consider code format as FREE? If yes, can I make them consider it as FIXED?

Comment: As the linked answer says: an asterisk on column 7 as comment-marker reuqires fixed-format compilation. And fixed-format compilation means columns 1-6 are reserved for line-numbers and you have to care about alll the stuff with "area A" and "area B" and what goes where (so no DISPLAY starting on the same column as PROGRAM-ID etc.)....

Comment: Sadly, this got closed as I was answering it, and the linked duplicate doesn't really answer the question of how to make the online compilers consider the source code as fixed format.

Comment: @cschneid I think an answer addressing caveats on commenting in online compilers would be a useful addition _to the target_.

Comment: @TylerH added new answer to target as you indicated.